# Is there any way by which we can track the fingerprints of Artifacts in AWS CodeBuild / CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Is there any way by which we can track build artifacts fingerprints in AWS CodeBuild / CodePipeline, something similar to that we have in Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodePipeline can list the artifacts used by a given pipeline execution:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_ListActionExecutions.html

Comment: But, this does not track the changes to artifacts over multiple builds.

Comment: Each pipeline execution has a different set of artifacts, so they're effectively immutable.